Android CarEvsService
I have been exploring CarEvsService in android lately. With a google CameraEvsPreview App(https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:packages/services/Car/tests/CarEvsCameraPreviewApp/), I could successfully see a preview of one camera at a time.
Google also claims that Multi camera access is supported for EVS, when multiple cameras are accessed as  a group.
https://source.android.com/docs/automotive/evs/multi_camera
On trying this it didn't work out  as expected.
Also it was mentioned in documentation that, for this to work Synchronization Framework(https://source.android.com/docs/core/graphics/sync ) must be supported.
Does anybody know

how to make Multi camera access work in CarEvsService ?
how to enable the Synchronization Framework in android?

